# Не могу подключится к БД с помощью hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

Не могу подключится к БД с помощью hibernate, при запуске отладочный вывод выдает следующую инфу. В чем может быть проблема? Или что то не замечаю в коде?

```
июл 17, 2019 2:48:45 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.4.3.Final}
июл 17, 2019 2:48:46 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.0.Final}
июл 17, 2019 2:48:47 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
июл 17, 2019 2:48:47 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001005: using driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/songs?useSSL=true]
июл 17, 2019 2:48:47 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {useUnicode=false, user=root, password=****, characterEncoding=UTF-8}
июл 17, 2019 2:48:47 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
июл 17, 2019 2:48:47 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections <init>
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
июл 17, 2019 2:48:48 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
июл 17, 2019 2:48:48 PM org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.JtaPlatformInitiator initiateService
INFO: HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
```

Файл конфигурации выглядит следующим образом

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">
            jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/songs?useSSL=true
        </property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql">true</property>

        <property name="hibernate.transaction.auto_close_session">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.useUnicode">false</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">UTF-8</property>

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: 1) Что значит "не получается подключиться"? В логе проблем не вижу(там везде написано `[INFO]`, если есть ошибка должно быть написано `[ERROR]`).
2) Попробуйте использовать не `hibernation.cfg` а `persistence.xml`
3) У вас Maven?

Comment: По логу у вас все нормально подключилось

Comment: В том то и проблема, что вроде бы все нормально, но дальнейшая работа не возможна, к БД не подключается. Хотя в отладочном выводе ничего не тображается.
Через persistence.xml работает все нормально, а если с помощью hibernation.cfg то вот такая проблемка.

Comment: вы так и не пояснили, `Что значит "не получается подключиться"?`